# Cannot find module 'node-sass

Tags: angular, module, find, node-sass

> *Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'*

When I run

`ng serve --port`

got this error and try to install the `node-sass` using the command

```
npm install node-sass
```

Then got the below

> (ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(40,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner')

Then I install this `npm i @zxing/ngx-scanner@1.3.0`.

But this time I got a first error which is

> Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

please help, thanks

Comment: try this command - npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass

Comment: or this one.. npm install --save-dev node-sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
`npm install --save-dev node-sass`
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(44,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.component.ts(7,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.component.ts(8,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/library'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.module.ts(8,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.

Comment: i got this error recently. So i run this npm install --save-dev node-sass but i got the same error which is above. Please help.

Comment: npm i @zxing/ngx-scanner

Answer (score 2):

npm install --save-dev node-sass

this works for me!!! Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. this will definitely resolve the Node-sass Issue in your project.

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: i got this error recently. So i run this npm install --save-dev node-sass but i got the same error which is above. Please help.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(44,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.component.ts(7,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.component.ts(8,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/library'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.module.ts(8,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
npm install @types/node-sass
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(44,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.component.ts(7,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.component.ts(8,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/library'.
src/app/qr-code-payment/qr-code-payment.module.ts(8,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@zxing/ngx-scanner'.

Comment: i got this error recently. So i run this npm install --save-dev node-sass but i got the same error which is above. Please help.